# Clock Display in BlueJ with GUI

Tags: java, bluej, displayobject

Currently the display works fine. I coded the minutes run act as seconds for simulation clock display. It's works fine but when it is 12:59, it should be 1 instead of 0. I couldn't figure it out to remove 00:00 should be 01:00 after 12:59.

clock.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Clock
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private ClockDisplay clock;
    private boolean clockRunning = false;
    private TimerThread timerThread;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Clock
     */
    public Clock()
    {
        makeFrame();
        clock = new ClockDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void start()
    {
        clockRunning = true;
        timerThread = new TimerThread();
        timerThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void stop()
    {
        clockRunning = false;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void step()
    {
        clock.timeTick();
        label.setText(clock.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * 'About' function: show the 'about' box.
     */
    private void showAbout()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, 
                    "Clock Version 1.0\n" +
                    "A simple interface for the 'Objects First' clock display project",
                    "About Clock", 
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Quit function: quit the application.
     */
    private void quit()
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }


    /**
     * Create the Swing frame and its content.
     */
    private void makeFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Clock");
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 60, 1, 60));

        makeMenuBar(frame);

        // Specify the layout manager with nice spacing
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(12, 12));

        // Create the image pane in the center
        label = new JLabel("00:00", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Font displayFont = label.getFont().deriveFont(96.0f);
        label.setFont(displayFont);
        //imagePanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create the toolbar with the buttons
        JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
        toolbar.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(e -> start());
        toolbar.add(startButton);

        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(e -> stop());
        toolbar.add(stopButton);

        JButton stepButton = new JButton("Step");
        stepButton.addActionListener(e -> step());
        toolbar.add(stepButton);

        // Add toolbar into panel with flow layout for spacing
        JPanel flow = new JPanel();
        flow.add(toolbar);

        contentPane.add(flow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // building is done - arrange the components      
        frame.pack();

        // place the frame at the center of the screen and show
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Create the main frame's menu bar.
     * 
     * @param frame   The frame that the menu bar should be added to.
     */
    private void makeMenuBar(JFrame frame)
    {
        final int SHORTCUT_MASK =
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenu menu;
        JMenuItem item;

        // create the File menu
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(menu);

        item = new JMenuItem("About Clock...");
            item.addActionListener(e -> showAbout());
        menu.add(item);

        menu.addSeparator();

        item = new JMenuItem("Quit");
            item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, SHORTCUT_MASK));
            item.addActionListener(e -> quit());
        menu.add(item);
    }

    class TimerThread extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (clockRunning) {
                step();
                pause();
            }
        }

        private void pause()
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);   // pause for 300 milliseconds
            }
            catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

clock.java should be locked as this is working properly.

numDisplay.java

```
/**
 * The NumberDisplay class represents a digital number display that can hold
 * values from zero to a given limit. The limit can be specified when 
 * creating the display. The values range from zero (inclusive) to limit-1. 
 * If used,
 * for example, for the seconds on a digital clock, the limit would be 60, 
 * resulting in display values from 0 to 59. When incremented, the display 
 * automatically rolls over to zero when reaching the limit.
 */
public class NumberDisplay
{
    private int limit = 13;
    private int value;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class NumberDisplay.
     * Set the limit at which the display rolls over.
     */
    public NumberDisplay(int rollOverLimit)
    {
        limit = rollOverLimit; 
        value = 1;
    }
    /*
     * 
     */

    /**
     * Return the current value.
     */
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Return the display value (that is, the current value as a two-digit
     * String. If the value is less than ten, it will be padded with a leading
     * zero).
     */
    public String getDisplayValue()
    {
        if(value < 10) {
            return "0" + value; // stay 0 appears in left 
        }
        else {
            return "" + value; // none to show in right of the display
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of the display to the new specified value. If the new
     * value is less than zero or over the limit, do nothing.
     */
    public void setValue(int replacementValue)
    {
        if((replacementValue >= 2) & (replacementValue < limit)) {
            value = replacementValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Increment the display value by one, rolling over to zero if the
     * limit is reached.
     */
    public void increment()
    {
        value = (value + 1) % limit; // this is already the time by 1 
    }
}
```

I also left comments to help understanding what they are running program.

This is last one called "Display" which is named ClockDisplay.java:

```
/**
 * The ClockDisplay class implements a digital clock display for a
 * European-style 24 hour clock. The clock shows hours and minutes. The 
 * range of the clock is 00:00 (midnight) to 23:59 (one minute before 
 * midnight).
 * 
 * The clock display receives "ticks" (via the timeTick method) every minute
 * and reacts by incrementing the display. This is done in the usual clock
 * fashion: the hour increments when the minutes roll over to zero.
 */
public class ClockDisplay
{
    private NumberDisplay hours;    // runs from 1 am/pm to 11:59 am/pm
    private NumberDisplay minutes;  // This will running like 
                                    //  seconds act as minutes.
    private String displayString;    // simulates the actual display

    /**
     * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor 
     * creates a new clock set at 00:00.
     */
    public ClockDisplay()
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(13); // set great than 13; runs from 1am to 12 noon
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60); // 60 minutes is one hour
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor
     * creates a new clock set at the time specified by the 
     * parameters.
     */
    public ClockDisplay(int hour, int minute)
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(13);
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
        setTime(hour, minute);
    }

    /**
     * This method should get called once every minute - it makes
     * the clock display go one minute forward.
     */
    public void timeTick()
    {
        minutes.increment();
        if(minutes.getValue() == 1) {  // on clock at after 12 am or pm.
            hours.increment(); // after 60 mins, next per hour.
        }
        updateDisplay(); // updating to return 
    }

    /**
     * Set the time of the display to the specified hour and
     * minute.
     */
    public void setTime(int hour, int minute)
    {
        hours.setValue(hour);       // hours will be set on display
        minutes.setValue(minute);   // minutes will be set on display
        updateDisplay();            // updating the value to display
    }

    /**
     * Return the current time of this display in the format HH:MM.
     */
    public String getTime()
    {
        return displayString; // appears as messagebox to display the clock
    }

    /**
     * Update the internal string that represents the display.
     */
    private void updateDisplay()
    {
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
                        minutes.getDisplayValue(); //Updated the clock simulator 
    }
}
```

I'm still stuck with 00:00. need help?

Comment: `(replacementValue >= 2) & (replacementValue < limit)` is doing a bitwise "and" operation, which isn't what you want.  Start by replacing `&` with `&&`

Comment: Side note: your code violates Swing threading rules as you are making direct Swing calls from a background thread. You should look into using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: You also need a better understanding of concurrency in Swing. Swing is NOT thread safe and you should never modify the UI, or something the UI relies on, from outside  the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details. A [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) would be a better choice then `Thread` in this case

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Getting slow in my old age :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, replaced it with `&&` but nothing is changed because they're similar.

Comment: @Dev They're no similar, they perform to two types of operations - now you need to dig further into your code and inspect what is actually going - this is part of learning how to debug

Comment: @MadProgrammer take care, this is NO bitwise "and"! Since the operands are boolean values, this is the non-short-circuiting "and". ```&&``` is also called the "Conditional And", while ```&``` is just the "and" (if used with boolean). @Dev FYI

Comment: @Islingre I stand corrected, obviously spending to much time in C these days

Comment: Thought it might be useful to link to the Java Language Specification for the [Boolean Logical Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) for the non-short-circuiting "and" operator. /cc @MadProgrammer

Comment: @DavidConrad It's funny you should add that, because [Summary of Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) and [Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) don't make mention of `&` as a boolean operator, only as a bitwise operator (you're not wrong). I'm wondering if this is something that has been added in recent versions or something I just missed/ignored (I stopped working in Java professionally around 1.6/1.7 - just when the language was becoming interesting 

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's a good point, and I did see that it wasn't described that way in those sections. But I seem to recall that the boolean form of it has been around for some time. I think that's a defect in the specification. I'll look into how to let them know. Never filed a bug report against a standards document before. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of areas in your code which could better managed.

Let's start with...

```
public void increment() {
    value = (value + 1) % limit; // this is already the time by 1 
}
```

I can see what you're trying to do, but remember `13 % 13` is `0`, which is the starting point of your issues, while certainly clever, I would have used `setValue(value + 1)` and allowed `setValue` to perform the validation.

The reason for this is, you could supply a minimum and maximum allowable values, which `setValue` could then manage.

I would then change the `increment` method to return `true` when it "rolls" the value, this way it would be easier to determine when the value has reverted to its minimum state.

For brevity, these are the basic changes...

## `NumberDisplay`

```
public class NumberDisplay {

    private int minimum = 1;
    private int maximum = 13;
    private int value;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class NumberDisplay. Set the limit at
     * which the display rolls over.
     */
    public NumberDisplay(int maxumum, int minimum) {
        this.maximum = maxumum;
        this.minimum = minimum;
        value = 1;
    }

    //...

    /**
     * Set the value of the display to the new specified value. If the new
     * value is less than zero or over the limit, do nothing.
     */
    public boolean setValue(int replacementValue) {
        if (replacementValue >= maximum) {
            value = minimum;
            return true;
        } else {
            value = replacementValue;
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Increment the display value by one, rolling over to zero if the limit
     * is reached.
     */
    public boolean increment() {
```

//            value = (value + 1) % maximum; // this is already the time by 1 
            return setValue(value + 1);
        }
    }

## `ClockDisplay`

```
public class ClockDisplay {

        //...

        /**
         * This method should get called once every minute - it makes the clock
         * display go one minute forward.
         */
        public void timeTick() {
            if (minutes.increment()) {  // on clock at after 12 am or pm.
                hours.increment(); // after 60 mins, next per hour.
            }
            updateDisplay(); // updating to return 
        }

        //...

}
```

## Full example....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Clock {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private ClockDisplay clock;
    private boolean clockRunning = false;
    private TimerThread timerThread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((13 % 13));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Clock();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Clock
     */
    public Clock() {
        makeFrame();
        clock = new ClockDisplay(12, 0);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void start() {
        clockRunning = true;
        timerThread = new TimerThread();
        timerThread.start();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void stop() {
        clockRunning = false;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void step() {
        clock.timeTick();
        label.setText(clock.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * 'About' function: show the 'about' box.
     */
    private void showAbout() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                "Clock Version 1.0\n"
                + "A simple interface for the 'Objects First' clock display project",
                "About Clock",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Quit function: quit the application.
     */
    private void quit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Create the Swing frame and its content.
     */
    private void makeFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("Clock");
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 60, 1, 60));

        makeMenuBar(frame);

        // Specify the layout manager with nice spacing
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(12, 12));

        // Create the image pane in the center
        label = new JLabel("12:00", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Font displayFont = label.getFont().deriveFont(96.0f);
        label.setFont(displayFont);
        //imagePanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create the toolbar with the buttons
        JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
        toolbar.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(e -> start());
        toolbar.add(startButton);

        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(e -> stop());
        toolbar.add(stopButton);

        JButton stepButton = new JButton("Step");
        stepButton.addActionListener(e -> step());
        toolbar.add(stepButton);

        // Add toolbar into panel with flow layout for spacing
        JPanel flow = new JPanel();
        flow.add(toolbar);

        contentPane.add(flow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // building is done - arrange the components      
        frame.pack();

        // place the frame at the center of the screen and show
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(d.width / 2 - frame.getWidth() / 2, d.height / 2 - frame.getHeight() / 2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Create the main frame's menu bar.
     *
     * @param frame The frame that the menu bar should be added to.
     */
    private void makeMenuBar(JFrame frame) {
        final int SHORTCUT_MASK
                = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenu menu;
        JMenuItem item;

        // create the File menu
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(menu);

        item = new JMenuItem("About Clock...");
        item.addActionListener(e -> showAbout());
        menu.add(item);

        menu.addSeparator();

        item = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, SHORTCUT_MASK));
        item.addActionListener(e -> quit());
        menu.add(item);
    }

    class TimerThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while (clockRunning) {
                step();
                pause();
            }
        }

        private void pause() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);   // pause for 300 milliseconds
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            }
        }
    }

    public class NumberDisplay {

        private int minimum = 1;
        private int maximum = 13;
        private int value;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class NumberDisplay. Set the limit at
         * which the display rolls over.
         */
        public NumberDisplay(int maxumum, int minimum) {
            this.maximum = maxumum;
            this.minimum = minimum;
            value = 1;
        }

        /*
     * 
         */
        /**
         * Return the current value.
         */
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        /**
         * Return the display value (that is, the current value as a two-digit
         * String. If the value is less than ten, it will be padded with a
         * leading zero).
         */
        public String getDisplayValue() {
            if (value < 10) {
                return "0" + value; // stay 0 appears in left 
            } else {
                return "" + value; // none to show in right of the display
            }
        }

        /**
         * Set the value of the display to the new specified value. If the new
         * value is less than zero or over the limit, do nothing.
         */
        public boolean setValue(int replacementValue) {
            if (replacementValue >= maximum) {
                value = minimum;
                return true;
            } else {
                value = replacementValue;
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Increment the display value by one, rolling over to zero if the limit
         * is reached.
         */
        public boolean increment() {
//            value = (value + 1) % maximum; // this is already the time by 1 
            return setValue(value + 1);
        }
    }

    public class ClockDisplay {

        private NumberDisplay hours;    // runs from 1 am/pm to 11:59 am/pm
        private NumberDisplay minutes;  // This will running like 
        //  seconds act as minutes.
        private String displayString;    // simulates the actual display

        /**
         * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor creates a new
         * clock set at 00:00.
         */
        public ClockDisplay() {
            hours = new NumberDisplay(13, 1); // set great than 13; runs from 1am to 12 noon
            minutes = new NumberDisplay(60, 0); // 60 minutes is one hour
            updateDisplay();
        }

        /**
         * Constructor for ClockDisplay objects. This constructor creates a new
         * clock set at the time specified by the parameters.
         */
        public ClockDisplay(int hour, int minute) {
            this();
            setTime(hour, minute);
        }

        /**
         * This method should get called once every minute - it makes the clock
         * display go one minute forward.
         */
        public void timeTick() {
            if (minutes.increment()) {  // on clock at after 12 am or pm.
                hours.increment(); // after 60 mins, next per hour.
            }
            updateDisplay(); // updating to return 
        }

        /**
         * Set the time of the display to the specified hour and minute.
         */
        public void setTime(int hour, int minute) {
            System.out.println("setTime " + hour + ":" + minute);
            hours.setValue(hour);       // hours will be set on display
            minutes.setValue(minute);   // minutes will be set on display
            updateDisplay();            // updating the value to display
        }

        /**
         * Return the current time of this display in the format HH:MM.
         */
        public String getTime() {
            return displayString; // appears as messagebox to display the clock
        }

        /**
         * Update the internal string that represents the display.
         */
        private void updateDisplay() {
            displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":"
                    + minutes.getDisplayValue(); //Updated the clock simulator 
        }
    }
}
```

## Side note

You also need a better understanding of concurrency in Swing. Swing is NOT thread safe and you should never modify the UI, or something the UI relies on, from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details. A [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) would be a better choice then Thread in this case

Comment: This is no bitwise "and", it is just the usual logical "and" with disabled short-circuiting! Since the right operand has no side-effects, they are similar in this case!